# SvelteKit form get request

Tags: sveltekit

I am trying to set up a simple endpoint in SvelteKit that reads the input given in a form and returns the result of an SQL query. In my first attempt I used the form actions and wrote the following code in the `+page.server.js` file:

```js
export const actions = {
    default: async (event) => {
        let form_input = await event.request.formData();
        let query = {
            text: "select * from ux_return_shipments($1, $2, $3, $4)",
            values: [form_input.get('beg-dep-date') || null, form_input.get('end-dep-date') || null, form_input.get('beg-arr-date') || null, form_input.get('end-arr-date') || null
        }

        try {
            const result = await event.locals.pool.query(query);
            return result.rows;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
};
```

I am now trying to set up the same process using a `GET` request instead of a `POST` one but I am having difficulties setting up the endpoint. I tried to replace the above code with this template but it looks like the endpoint is not getting activated since I see no activity server side:

```js
export function GET({ url }) {
    console.log(url);
    return new Response("Test response");
};
```

What am I doing wrong? I see that using this code for an API endpoint (`+server.js` file) works correctly. I also checked the form element and the URL looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has the same problem I managed to solve it using this template:

```js
export const load = async (event) => {
    return ...
};
```

Using the `load` function I was able to set up a get endpoint and pass some data to the frontend using a `return`.